# How replace null value in data frame with median of two columned grouped value?

Tags: python, grouping, fillna

I have a data frame in Python which includes the frequency of using some food by individuals in a week. I would like to clean my data frame and replace null values with the median frequency of each food category that used by each individual. How can I replace the null value with meidan of each food category for each person?

```
user  ffq    food       food-category
 1     1     apple         fruit
 1     3     banana        fruit
 1     2     tomato      vegetables
 1   nan     carrot      vegetables
 1     3     potato      vegetables
 1    nan    peach        fruit
 2     3     apple        fruit
 2    nan    banana       fruit
 2     2     tomato       vegetables
 2     nan   carrot       vegetables
 2     3   peach          fruit
```

and the result should be like :

```
user  ffq    food       food-category
 1     1     apple         fruit
 1     3     banana        fruit
 1     2     tomato      vegetables
 1 **2.5**   carrot      vegetables
 1     3     potato      vegetables
 1   **2**   peach        fruit
 2     3     apple        fruit
 2   **3**   banana       fruit
 2     2     tomato       vegetables
 2   **2**   carrot       vegetables
 2     3     peach        fruit
```

I appreciate if anyone can help

Comment: I guess you you want to calculate the mean, not the median

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to fill the missing values with the *mean* of the groups instead of the *median*. We can use `.fillna()` along with `.groupby()` and `.transform()` functions to accomplish this with one line of code. First, let's create the DataFrame with the required columns.

```
# Create a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'user':['1','1','1','1','1','1', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2'], 
                   'ffq':[1, 3, 2, np.nan, 3, np.nan, 3, np.nan, 2, np.nan, 3],
                   'food-category':['fruit', 'fruit', 'vegetables', 'vegetables', 
                                    'vegetables', 'fruit', 'fruit', 'fruit', 'vegetables', 
                                    'vegetables', 'fruit']})
```

We can now fill the missing values with desired imputation method such as *mean*, *median* or *mode*. Below imputation is done with *mean* to get the result mentioned in the question.

```
# Apply fillna function within each group
df['ffq'] = df.groupby(['user', 'food-category']).transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
```

```
    user   ffq   food-category
0   1      1.0   fruit
1   1      3.0   fruit
2   1      2.0   vegetables
3   1      2.5   vegetables
4   1      3.0   vegetables
5   1      2.0   fruit
6   2      3.0   fruit
7   2      3.0   fruit
8   2      2.0   vegetables
9   2      2.0   vegetables
10  2      3.0   fruit
```

The `.transform()` method is used to perform group-specific computation, which is *mean* in this example, and it returns a like-indexed object. See [User Guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you do that. First we need to sort the values, so that they appear in the correct order when we use the groupby. Next we calculate the mean and afterwards we need to fill the `NaN`s with the series we extracted.

```
df = df.sort_values(['user','food-category'])
srs = df.dropna().groupby(['user','food-category']).agg({'ffq':'mean'})['ffq']
srs.index = df[df['ffq'].isnull()].index
df['ffq'] = df['ffq'].fillna(value=srs)
```

result

```
df.sort_index()
    user    ffq     food    food-category
0   1       1.0     apple   fruit
1   1       3.0     banana  fruit
2   1       2.0     tomato  vegetables
3   1       2.5     carrot  vegetables
4   1       3.0     potato  vegetables
5   1       2.0     peach   fruit
6   2       3.0     apple   fruit
7   2       3.0     banana  fruit
8   2       2.0     tomato  vegetables
9   2       2.0     carrot  vegetables
10  2       3.0     peach   fruit
```